# K-theory and usual (cohomoogical) Euler class

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

Can someone explain the difference (and hence the sense of studying) between the usual and K-theoretical Euler class? Most famous and for now the only difference is showed during computations of tensor product of two line bundles.

Namely $e^K(L_1\otimes L_2)\neq e^H(L_1\otimes L_2)$, where $e^K$ and $e^H$ are K-theory and cohomology Euler classes.

Any intuition or maybe an article?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is the K-theory Euler class?

Comment: http://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/kgeom.pdf for example here on page 158.